# ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am trying to convert mySQL stored procedure into postgrSQL Stored function. I am new to postgreSQL. First time I am trying to convert join Store procedure into store function. But I am getting following error

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type character varying in column 3.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function getsummarypagecontentsurveyform(numeric) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSummaryPageContentSurveyForm]     
    @nRoomAllocationID bigint
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  Employee.sEmpName, RoomInvestigatorMapping.sComment,
           Employee.sEmpName + ' : ' + RoomInvestigatorMapping.sComment as CommentsToDisplay
   FROM    RoomInvestigatorMapping INNER JOIN Employee 
        ON RoomInvestigatorMapping.nInvestigatorID = Employee.nEmpID
   Where    RoomInvestigatorMapping.nRoomAllocationID = @nRoomAllocationID 
END   
GO
```

**Store Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetSummaryPageContentSurveyForm (        
    p_nroom_allocation_id numeric)

    RETURNS Table(res_semp_name character varying,res_scomment character varying,
                  res_comments_to_display character varying)
AS $$
BEGIN
 Return Query    
   SELECT  employee.semp_name, roominvestigatormapping.scomment,
           employee.semp_name || ' : ' || roominvestigatormapping.scomment as comments_to_display
   FROM    roominvestigatormapping INNER JOIN employee 
           ON roominvestigatormapping.ninvestigator_id = employee.nemp_id
   Where   roominvestigatormapping.nroom_allocation_id = p_nroom_allocation_id; 
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL functions has to have defined result type. Runtime check if output is same like defined type. In your case third expression returns text instead varchar. You need to cast this expression to varchar explicitly:

```
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY    
    SELECT  employee.semp_name, roominvestigatormapping.scomment,
         (employee.semp_name || ' : ' || roominvestigatormapping.scomment)::varchar as comments_to_display
      FROM    roominvestigatormapping INNER JOIN employee 
        ON roominvestigatormapping.ninvestigator_id = employee.nemp_id
     WHERE   roominvestigatormapping.nroom_allocation_id = p_nroom_allocation_id; 
END;
$$
```

I used cast operator `::` :

```
somevalue::varchar
```

Comment: why third column returning `text` . is it because of concatenation of two string?

Comment: I tried using `::` but getting this `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 12: ...name || ' : ' || roominvestigatormapping.scomment as comment...`

Comment: @HKAK - in this case, result type is based on result type of operator `||`

Comment: @HKAK I had a bug there - casting should be before relabeling `AS xxx`